# How to count certain elements in an object array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to count occurance of every element in this JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Sena",
        "lastName": "Turan",
        "age": 19,
        "retired": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Çınar",
        "lastName": "Turan",
        "age": 1,
        "retired": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Ahmet",
        "lastName": "Turan",
        "age": 55,
        "retired": true
    }
]
```

Like how many "firstName" or "age" variables it contains. Anyone has an opinion on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce your array and up the count for every element in the objects of the array:

```js
const arr = [{ "firstName" : "Sena", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 19, "retired" : false}, {"firstName" : "Çınar", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 1, "retired" : false}, {"firstName" : "Ahmet", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 55, "retired" : true} ];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for(let el in curr) {
    acc[el] = acc[el] == null ? 1 : acc[el] + 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Your help is very much appreciated.

This works only if the JSON data is written in the JS file. I have an external local JSON file containing those variables. When I try this solution in this circumstances my output is: {
0: 1,
1: 1,
2: 1
} instead of 
{
  "firstName": 3,
  "lastName": 3,
  "age": 3,
  "retired": 3
}
Where am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Write `const arr = JSON.parse(file)` then @tunayvaz

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply go through all of the items and check for the specific item you want:

```js
const arr = [{ "firstName" : "Sena", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 19, "retired" : false}, {"firstName" : "Çınar", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 1, "retired" : false}, {"firstName" : "Ahmet", "lastName" : "Turan", "age" : 55, "retired" : true} ];
    
const count= (it) => {
  let count = 0;
  
  for (el of arr) {
    if(el[it]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};
    
console.log(count("firstName"));
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for your help. But I wonder what does that "el" and "it" variables represent? Sorry I'm just not familiar with JS.

Comment: the it simply is an argument you define, name doesn't really matter, could be anything:
the el is basically illustrates the element inside of the array. try to read about for loops, it would become more clear

Answer (score 1):

If I may add my attempt, this is written in ES6:

```
const countAppearance = key => {
    let count = 0;
    arr.forEach(record => (count += record[key] ? 1 : 0));
    return count;
};
```

@tunayvaz Also, one very CRUCIAL detail: all these functions don't actually check for the key itself, they check for the existence of the value of that key. Meaning, if you make all "age" undefined, it will give you 0, even though age appears in all 3 records. If you want a strictly working function, you might want to have a look at Object.keys() or something.

Comment: I think `const countAppearance = (arr,key) => arr.reduce((acc, rec) => acc + (Object.keys(rec).includes(key) ? 1 : 0), 0);` would be cleaner.

Comment: This is very important detail. Thank you for your countribution. Actually what I need was counting the values of the keys if they exist, not the key itself. My bad expressing.

Answer (score -1):

`yourArray.filter(person => 'age' in person).length` should work for the age, for an example. YOu can tweak it for other properties.